# Kafka Sink HDFS Unrecognized token

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I'm trying to write JSON with Kafka HDFS Sink.

I have the following properties (connect-standalone.properties):

```
key.converter.schemas.enable = false
value.converter.schemas.enable = false
schemas.enable=false
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

And on my properties:

```
format.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.json.JsonFormat
```

And I got the following exception:

> org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka connect failed due to serilization error
>
> ...
>   Caused By: org.apache.kafka.commom.errors.SerlizationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'test' : was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN at [Source: (byte[])"test" line: 1 column: 11]

My JSON is valid.

How can I solve it please?

*I'm trying also with sample JSON like:

```
{"key":"value"}
```

And still same error.

Thanks.

Comment: The data in your topic needs to be JSON. It looks like one message in the topic is only `"test"`

Comment: Can you show the both connect property files and the output of the console consumer from the beginning of the topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, not all the messages in the topic are actually JSON objects. The *latest messages* might be valid, or the Kafka values might be valid (not the keys, though), but the error shows that it tried to read a plain string, `(byte[])"test"`, which is not valid

If you only want text data into HDFS, you could use String format, however that won't have Hive integration

```
format.class=io.confluent.connect.hdfs.string.StringFormat
```

If you did want to use Hive with this format, you would need to define the JSON Serde yourself

Comment: I got an exeption "Class io.confluent.connect.hdfs.string.StringFormat could not be found."

Comment: It's only available in the newer versions of Confluent

Comment: Ok, I will check my version, For older version what is my alternative?

Comment: You can delete that topic or set the retention to a small value to clean out non JSON messages. But if not all the messages are JSON, you'll continue to see a similar error. Can you please edit your question to include the console consumer output from the beginning of the topic?

Comment: Ok, I will try. About the console output - Sorry but I cant copy from my environment. Thank you!

Comment: Alright. The other alternative if you're using Schema Registry would be Avro data, which works much better in Hadoop processes than JSON because you get a defined schema with the data